# Platform for stateful frame-by-frame processing

Tags: apache-kafka, time-series, streaming, apache-flink

Modern stream processing engines tend to focus on parallel processing of big data. This is great when the desired results are calculated from aggregates over the entire set or subset(filtered) of the whole dataset. In contrast to this I need to process data sequentially, where a change from one row to the next has meaning and changes what has to be done next. All data is time-series data. As an example, imagine a video game generating the results according to the current situation and the inputs of the player. Spark kind of allows this with e.g. mapGroupsWithState(), but I believe it's not what it's designed for, as this case doesn't need distributing data across a cluster to do processing on(because as data needs to be processed sequentially,it should benefit from holding the state in one place and passing all data through a single point of processing close to that state). I've looked at flink but I didn't find anything related to stream processing frame-by-frame.

Is anything out there for solving this type of problems? I don't want to re-invent the wheel.

Thank you.

Comment: Unclear what you mean "frame by frame". A single partitioned kafka topic is sequentially ordered and state aggregation is completely optional, but can be handled by either Spark, Flink, or just Kafka Streams/KsqlDB. Any processor will already be consuming events in the order they're created

Comment: Thank you. I am already using kafka for the reason you mentioned. The problem is, the stream processing platforms are focused on solving problems like "what's the max of  variable X" or "filter by variable Y=...", and in my problem I need to detect when X changes from 0 to 1 and back to 0, and after that the analysis changes because the value of Y has a different meaning than before the change in X. So the variables' meaning are context dependent, and the context can only be determined by the evolution of other variables through the stream.

Comment: Max and filter are just functions. If you stored data persistently in a state store like in Kafka Streams, or used a function like reduceByKey instead, you have access to inspect state of prior data

Comment: I understand that I have access to to inspect the state of prior data. I'm looking for a platform that does that.

Comment: I just said Kafka Streams

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do event-at-a-time temporal pattern matching and time-series analysis with Flink.

For an easier-to-use, higher-level API, look at the docs for doing [pattern recognition with Flink SQL](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/dev/table/sql/queries/match_recognize/). For a more powerful pattern recognition library, see the docs for [Flink's CEP library](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/libs/cep/).

If you prefer to work directly with the lower-level building blocks of stateful, event-at-a-time stream processing, then the best place to start in Flink is with the `KeyedProcessFunction`.

Using your example of analyzing a stream of events from a video game, if you want to separately (and in parallel) process streams from different players, you would do something like this:

```java
events
  .keyBy(event -> event.playerId)
  .process(new MyKeyedProcessFunction())
  ...
```

but if you can't meaningfully key-partition the stream, then you can do this:

```java
events
  .keyBy("a constant")
  .process(new MyKeyedProcessFunction())
```

The reason you probably want to use a `KeyedStream` even if you can't take advantage of parallelism is that Flink's keyed state and timers are easier to work and more flexible than non-keyed state.

See [the process function docs](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/dev/datastream/operators/process_function/) for more information.

Comment: Thank you David. I'm going to study the solutions you suggested.